# Can't add OnClickListener to a Button in a Dialog

Tags: java, android, function, android-alertdialog

I have written a function to handle showing of `Dialog` but I am not able to use `OnClickListener` in it. What is wrong with my code can any one tell me?

Here is my function

```
private void showInputDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainDashboard.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.frg_dialog_change_pass);

    btn_save_password=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save_password);
    btn_cancel_pass=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_pass);
    edtOldpass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtOldpass);
    edtNewpass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNewpass);
    edtConfirmpass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmpass);

    dialog.show();///Show the dialog.

    btn_save_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainDashboard.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Activity.findViewById()` will look for the `View` in the layout of your `Activity` (the one you've set by calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`).

I guess those `View`s are in your `Dialog` layout, so you need to call `findViewById()` on your `Dialog` instance:

```
btn_save_password = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_password);
btn_cancel_pass = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_pass);
edtOldpass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtOldpass);
edtNewpass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtNewpass);
edtConfirmpass = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmpass);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare this globally above oncreate
private android.app.AlertDialog dialog;

android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainDashboard.this);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View alertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_dialog_change_pass, null);
        alertDialog.setView(alertView);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        Button btn_save_password= (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_password);

        btn_save_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do your stuff here
            }
        });

        if(dialog !=null)
            dialog.dismiss();

        dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
private void showInputDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainDashboard.this);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainDashboard.this).inflate(R.layout.frg_dialog_change_pass);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    btn_save_password=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save_password);
    btn_cancel_pass=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_pass);
    edtOldpass=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtOldpass);
    edtNewpass=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtNewpass);
    edtConfirmpass=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtConfirmpass);
    dialog.show();///Show the dialog.
    btn_save_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainDashboard.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

Basically you have to use `findViewById` with the `view` which is used for `dialog` .